# How to use a wildcard when querying belongs_to relationships in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord

I have a search/filter form where the user may select none to many parameters from which to filter records.  The filters could include a specific user_id, or company_id, or project_id, etc.  Any combination of these parameters could be submitted to filter records by.

What I'm trying to do is create as simple a query as possible and not need to re-query a subset.

I could pull this off by using more logic in the query...but, it seems there should be a rails way.

```
Thing.where( params[:user_id].present? ? user_id: params[:user_id] : "user_id IS NOT NULL" ).
   where( params[:company_id].present? ? company_id: params[:company_id] : "company_id IS NOT NULL" )
```

What I'm striving for is something cleaner...like:

```
Thing.where( user_id: params.fetch(:user_id, '*') )
```

Then, I could chain all the available search params like this:

```
Thing.where(
   user_id: params.fetch(:user_id, '*'),
   company_id: params.fetch(:company_id, '*'),
   project_id: params.fetch(:project_id, '*')
)
```

## Another approach

Thing.where('') will return all Things.  So, I could do something like:

```
Thing.where( params[:user_id].present? ? { user_id: params[:user_id] } : '' )
```

But, this doesn't seem like the rails way.

Is there a way to do this?  Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Just create a model that takes the parameters as input and creates a scope:

```
class ThingFilter
  include ActiveModel::Model
  include ActiveModel::Attributes
  attribute :user_id
  attribute :company_id
  attribute :project_id

  def resolve(scope = Thing.all)
    attributes.inject(scope) do |filtered, (attr_name, value)|
      if !value.present? 
        scope.merge(Thing.where.not(attr_name => nil))
      else
        scope.merge(Thing.where(attr_name => value))
      end
    end
  end
end
```

```
class Thing < ApplicationRecord
  def self.filter(**kwargs)
    ThingFilter.new(**kwargs).resolve(self.where)
  end
end
```

```
@things = Thing.filter(
  params.permit(:user_id, :company_id, :project_id)
)
```

This is extremely easy to test and lets you add features like validations if needed without making a mess of your controller. You can also bind it to forms.

Comment: Very solid and detailed answer!  Thank you so much!  This is a very flexible option.  I hadn't thought of this approach...I think I can put this to use in some other areas of my app too!

Comment: Just a question (not a critique) why `merge` over the direct call to `where`/`where.not`. These methods will both spawn and return a new "scope"

Comment: @engineersmnky I originally had a private method which gave a scope per attribute so it was `scope.merge(filter_by_attribute(attr_name, value))` but shortened the example and didn't change it. The idea is that it gives the method latitude to return any scope instead of just something compatible with the arguments for `.where`.

Answer (score 1):

There's a method called [`#merge`](https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/SpawnMethods/merge) which can be used in this case.

```rb
@things = Thing.all
@things = @things.merge(-> { where(user_id: params[:user_id]) }) if params[:user_id].present?
@things = @things.merge(-> { where(company_id: params[:company_id]) }) if params[:company_id].present?
@things = @things.merge(-> { where(project_id: params[:project_id]) }) if params[:project_id].present?
```

Although it's not the most concise way to do it, it's pretty readable in my opinion.

---

Found a concise way to do it, but use it according to your opinion on readability.

```rb
@things =
  params.slice(:user_id, :company_id, :project_id).
    reduce(Thing.all) do |relation, (column, value)|
      relation.where(column => value)
    end
```

Comment: Merge is a good option.  It's similar to my current approach, but isolates each subsequent merge to its own instance var...which might improve readability.  Thanks!

Comment: There is reason to pass a lambda. Just use `@things.merge(where(user_id: params[:user_id]))`

Comment: Is this functionally different than @things = @things.where(user_id: params[:user_id]) if params[:user_id] ?

Answer (score 1):

It feels like you may be coding that which the Ransack gem already provides.

It accepts search parameters, such as `user_id_eq` and `company_name_present`, and sort parameters, and converts them to the required SQL.

https://github.com/activerecord-hackery/ransack

Comment: Thanks!  I use Ransack for some search functionality and pagination goodies.  I'll dig deeper to see how it could help me in this scenario.